# equivalent for numpy.transpose and numpy.expand_dims in C++ (OpenCV)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, transpose

I am trying to convert the following codes written in Python to C++:

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImages(frames, 1.0, (SAMPLE_SIZE, SAMPLE_SIZE), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=True)
blob = np.transpose(blob, (1, 0, 2, 3))
blob = np.expand_dims(blob, axis=0)
```

However, I do not know how to do `np.transpose` and `np.expand_dims` in C++ and or OpenCV. Any help or a suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this from the action_recognition.py sample ?

Comment: Yes. it is from action_recognition.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this (yea, i know, it looks pretty weird ...):

```
// the input blob structure for the resnet-34_kinetics action recognition,
// taken from:
// https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/test/test_onnx_importer.cpp#L611
//
Mat blob5D(const std::vector<Mat> &images) {
    Mat blob0 = blobFromImages(images, 1.0, Size(112, 112), Scalar(114.7748, 107.7354, 99.4750), true, true);

    Net permute;
    LayerParams lp;
    int order[] = {1, 0, 2, 3};
    lp.set("order", DictValue::arrayInt<int*>(&order[0], 4));
    permute.addLayerToPrev("perm", "Permute", lp);
    permute.setInput(blob0);
    Mat input0 = permute.forward().clone();

    int dims[] = {1, 3, 16, 112, 112}; // 16 == time batch size
    return input0.reshape(0, 5, &dims[0]);
}
```

then, you should probably change the way, images are sampled --
not consecutively (like in the py sample), but divide your clip into e.g. 16 equidistant steps (like it is done in the training code)

gl with it !

Comment: Thank you very much @berak. Problem solved! 
However, I did not understand the solution at all! Is there any proper source to read and get familiar what is going on? :->

Comment: again, it's taken from some dnn unit test (see link in the comment) and yea, took me a while to grok it, too. maybe [have a look at the original pytorch repo](https://github.com/kenshohara/video-classification-3d-cnn-pytorch)